# Merge multiple data files (with multiple columns) that are parts of a time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multiple time series data (txt files) that form one time series. 
Here is an oversimplified example:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime as dt

    df1_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [15/03/2019 10:00:11.000, 15/03/2019 10:00:12.000 , 15/03/2019 10:00:13.000],
   'Cond [mS/cm]': [7.45, 7.45, 7.45],
   'Temp [C]': [8.22, 8.22, 8.22],
    'Sal [PSU]': [7.63, 7.63, 7.63]})

    df1_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [30/03/2019 10:00:11.000, 30/03/2019 10:00:12.000 , 30/03/2019 10:00:13.000],
   'Cond [mS/cm]': [7.45, 7.45, 7.45],
   'Temp [C]': [8.22, 8.22, 8.22],
    'Sal [PSU]': [7.63, 7.63, 7.63]})

    df2_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [15/03/2019 10:00:11.000, 15/03/2019 10:00:12.000 , 15/03/2019 10:00:13.000],
   'Cond_2 [mS/cm]': [7.47, 7.47, 7.47],
   'Temp_2 [C]': [8.22, 8.22, 8.22],
    'Sal_2 [PSU]': [7.67, 7.67, 7.67]})  

     df2_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [30/03/2019 10:00:11.000, 30/03/2019 10:00:12.000 , 30/03/2019 10:00:13.000],
   'Cond_2 [mS/cm]': [7.47, 7.47, 7.47],
   'Temp_2 [C]': [8.22, 8.22, 8.22],
    'Sal_2 [PSU]': [7.67, 7.67, 7.67]})
```

Where df1 means data from sensor 1, df1_1 and df_2 are next fragments of time series.

I want to combine all  into one big `DataFrame`.

So far I've:

- genereted file containing complete time series (data from sensors
  might have unexpected gaps),
- read files as `DataFrames`,
- defined headers,
- set 'Date' column as an `index` of each `DataFrame`.

Then I wanted to `join` `DataFrames` to the complete time series by:

```
full_date = dates.join([df1_1, df1_2], how = "outer")
```

but I recived an error:

> ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values: Index(['Cond [mS/cm]',
>   'Press [DBar]', 'Temp [C]', 'Sal [PSU]',
>          'Dens.anom [kg/m3]', 'SOS [m/s]'],
>         dtype='object')

To check if the problem is really in the headers I merged files with slightly different headers (different headers = different sensor). Then I've recived:

```
    complete_df = ({' ':[01/04/2019 00:00:01, 01/04/2019 00:00:01 , 01/04/2019 00:00:01,
    'Cond [mS/cm]': [NaN, NaN, NaN],
    'Temp [C]': [NaN, NaN, NaN],
    'Sal [PSU]': [NaN, NaN, NaN],
    'Cond_2 [mS/cm]': [NaN, NaN, NaN],
    'Temp_2 [C]': [NaN, NaN, NaN],
    'Sal_2 [PSU]': [NaN, NaN, NaN]})
```

that is quite reasonable except that the data are not in the right order.

My question is: how should I combine all Dataframes to get one big DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your dates as strings, than convert them to DateTime. After that use pd.concat.There is still the issue that you are duplicating columns potentially unnecessarily (Cond[mS/cm], Cond_2[mS/cm]). Alternativelly you could have all columns named the same and pass one additional column with the sensor identifier (i.e "sensor":1)

```
import pandas as pd

df1_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['15/03/2019 10:00:11.000', '15/03/2019 10:00:12.000' , '15/03/2019 10:00:13.000'],
'Cond [mS/cm]': [7.45, 7.45, 7.45],
   'Temp [C]': [8.22, 8.22, 8.22],
    'Sal [PSU]': [7.63, 7.63, 7.63]})

df1_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['30/03/2019 10:00:11.000', '30/03/2019 10:00:12.000' , "30/03/2019 10:00:13.000"],
   'Cond [mS/cm]': [7.45, 7.45, 7.45],
   'Temp [C]': [8.22, 8.22, 8.22],
    'Sal [PSU]': [7.63, 7.63, 7.63]})

df2_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['15/03/2019 10:00:11.000', '15/03/2019 10:00:12.000' , '15/03/2019 10:00:13.000'],
   'Cond_2 [mS/cm]': [7.47, 7.47, 7.47],
   'Temp_2 [C]': [8.22, 8.22, 8.22],
    'Sal_2 [PSU]': [7.67, 7.67, 7.67]})  

df2_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['30/03/2019 10:00:11.000', '30/03/2019 10:00:12.000' , '30/03/2019 10:00:13.000'],
   'Cond_2 [mS/cm]': [7.47, 7.47, 7.47],
   'Temp_2 [C]': [8.22, 8.22, 8.22],
    'Sal_2 [PSU]': [7.67, 7.67, 7.67]}) 

complete_df  = pd.concat([df1_1,df1_2,df2_1,df2_2],ignore_index=True)
complete_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(complete_df['Date'])
complete_df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
complete_df.fillna(0)
```

[image]